# Commit a wrapper only when all the scripts are complete

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to commit a wrapper file only all the scripts placed inside the wrapper is success.

Since Oracle expects the client to send the commit signal, is it possible somehow without sending it explicit?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? How do you know if a script is successful - should it return a specific value? There are a number of ways to control the flow of execution, but the best way depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Have you looked into using PL/SQL or CASE expressions to accomplish what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the script in sqlplus, you can use the `WHENEVER SQLERROR` command to exit on an error.

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
@script3.sql
COMMIT;
```

If your scripts contain DDL commands, this won't work because DDL *always* does an implicit commit beforehand.